# Iterating through a multidimensional array to find the element matching that of a single dimensional array

Tags: vb.net

I have an 3 array's (Drink, Food, Desert), as well as a multidimensional array named prices that stores prices for 8 items on the menu. I have a sub procedure that deals with transferring the item from the array in the listbox to the textboxes below, but am having trouble with price considering it is multidimensional

Comment: Why would you store an item and its price in different arrays?  Using a classes and collections of them means never having to search for a price.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Ditto @Plutonix.  Also, Jake, show your code.

Answer (score 0):

You would be better thinking of your menu and each item as objects for example, a menu contains a list of menu items and a menu item is an object that has properties such as a name, a type(Drink/Main Course/Dessert/Side),a description and a price.

So you might be better creating a Menu object that contains a list of all the menu items to be stored in it.

So first of all you want to define what your MenuItems are .. somthing like the code below. You will also want to define what sort of item it is. That is done by the `Enum..End Enum` block.

```
Friend Class FoodMenuItem

    Enum ItemType
        Drink
        MainCourse
        Dessert
        Side
    End Enum

    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Price As Decimal
    Public Property Catagory As ItemType
    Public Property Description As String

    Public Sub New(newName As String, newPrice As Decimal, newCatagory As ItemType, newDescription As String)
        Name = newName
        Price = newPrice
        Catagory = newCatagory
        Description = newDescription
    End Sub
End Class
```

Next you want to create a menu which is simply a list of menu items

```
Dim FoodItems As New List(Of FoodMenuItem)
```

To add a food item to the list you need to create it and add it to your list

```
Dim itemtoAdd1 As New FoodMenuItem("Pasta", 4.95D, FoodMenuItem.ItemType.MainCourse, "Delicious pasta with parmesan cheese")
Dim itemtoadd2 As New FoodMenuItem("Beer", 3D, FoodMenuItem.ItemType.Drink, "Cool and refreshing")
Dim itemtoadd3 As New FoodMenuItem("Red Wine", 3.3D, FoodMenuItem.ItemType.Drink, "Fruity")
Dim itemtoadd4 As New FoodMenuItem("White Wine", 3.5D, FoodMenuItem.ItemType.Drink, "Dry")
Dim itemtoadd5 As New FoodMenuItem("Salad", 4.5D, FoodMenuItem.ItemType.MainCourse, "Crisp Salad with iceberg lettuce, tomatoes and beetroot")
Dim itemtoadd6 As New FoodMenuItem("Chocolate Fudge Cake", 4.25D, FoodMenuItem.ItemType.Dessert, "Indulgent fudge cake with fresh whipped cream")
Dim itemtoadd7 As New FoodMenuItem("Ice Cream", 4.5D, FoodMenuItem.ItemType.Dessert, "In a choice of flavours with the topping of your choice")

FoodItems.Add(itemtoAdd1)
FoodItems.Add(itemtoadd2)
FoodItems.Add(itemtoadd3)
FoodItems.Add(itemtoadd4)
FoodItems.Add(itemtoadd5)
FoodItems.Add(itemtoadd6)
FoodItems.Add(itemtoadd7)
```

So at some point you want to have these items in their appropriate listboxes. You could use this sub ..

```
Private Sub UpdateList(listBoxToUpdate As ListBox, category As FoodMenuItem.ItemType)
    listBoxToUpdate.Items.Clear()
    listBoxToUpdate.Items.AddRange((From item As FoodMenuItem In FoodItems Where item.Category = category Select item).ToArray)
    listBoxToUpdate.DisplayMember = "Name"
End Sub
```

And use it like this, assuming listbox names of ListBoxDrinks,ListBoxMainCourse,ListBoxDessert

```
UpdateList(ListBoxDrinks, FoodMenuItem.ItemType.Drink)
UpdateList(ListBoxMainCourse, FoodMenuItem.ItemType.MainCourse)
UpdateList(ListBoxDessert, FoodMenuItem.ItemType.Dessert)
```

When you click an item in say `ListBoxDrinks` you would get the item and place its name in one textbox and its price in another textbox like this ..

```
Private Sub ListBoxDrinks_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBoxDrinks.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim selectedDrink As FoodMenuItem = CType(ListBoxDrinks.SelectedItem, FoodMenuItem)
    TextBoxItemName.Text = selectedDrink.Name
    TextBoxItemPrice.Text = selectedDrink.Price.ToString("C")
End Sub
```

That should do it. By the way `ToString("C")` in the last line will format the text to your local currency.